# Syntax error in python machine learning sklearn code mosh Python course. Id appreciate if someone could hep me

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, syntax

I am doing a Python course with Mosh programming and am getting an error with some machine learning code

The code is this ->

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_train = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
score
```

I am getting an error that says ->

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0880d58e9ac4> in <module>
 10 model = DecisionTreeClassifier
 11 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_train = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
---> 12 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
 13 predictions = model.predict(X_test)
 14 

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

I'm new to these libraries and am able to resolve the issue
Id grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake comes from the fact you are not generating the instance of the model.

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier
```

This is incorrect, because `DecisionTreeClassifier` is a function, not a method. To create the model, you need to replace the line of code above with:

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

This will create model and now you can pass data to fit it and perform all further operations (predict, score, etc...).

Also, as Gavin Wong pointed, there's a mistake when using `train_test_split()` because you defined `y_train` twice.

Comment: I used your solution.
It Worked.
Thank you for your help.